# Xamarin.Forms.Datagrid Event Handler

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, datagrid

Finally used Nuget [Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/)  but know I am stuck with DataGrid.ItemSelected property.

I am using MVVM pattern with Commands, but DataGrid needs EventHandler for ItemSelected (I hope this is alternative for SelectionChangedCommand in CollectionView).

Is there way to use existing command as ItemSelected or if not how should I implement it using MVVM, main goal of command should be to update value of some IsSelected boolean value.

Comment: you can use [EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior).  Or DataGrid supports a bindable `ItemSelected` property

Comment: I was one vacation for one week and haven't been able to test it live. I implemented [EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) with no compilation errors but won't be able to test it until Monday. Looking forward to inform you if it was helpful or not

Comment: @Jason Tried using EventToCommand but getting 
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
`

I can't debug it so I tried implementing simple event handler in code-behind (but it destroys my MVVM structure)

Comment: What does the`InnerException` property show?  What do you mean "I can't debug it"?  If you want additional help you need to update your question to include the relevant detail about what you tried and the error you're getting

Comment: I am not quite sure how to catch that inner exception, when I put breakpoints on view it just throws this. I am not great with debugging Xamarin

Comment: It’s a property of the exception object.  You don’t need to catch it.  This is basic c# debugging

Comment: How can I get property of unhandled exception?

Comment: the debugger should give you access to the exception object - you can set it to break on unhandled exceptions, which is what appears to be happening already.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create binding on `DataGrid.SelectedItem` , and do something in `Setter` method .

```
//xaml

<dg:DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

```
//viewmodel

private object _SelectedItem;
public oibject SelectedItem
{
   get
   {
      return SelectedItem;
   }
   set
   {
      _SelectedItem = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
      
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: @Herien Wolf Does it work or not ?

Comment: Was on vacation, sorry for late replay but this isn't my problem, I have SelectedItem property binded well. My problems is EventHandler for ItemSelected. But thanks anyway

Comment: Ok , no problem , happy coding `